# mongoose typescript type for updateOne

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I have the following code :

```
async setProcessedSubUser(id: ObjectId, processSub: ProcessSubscriptionInterface): Promise<???> {
  return this.userModel.updateOne({ _id: id }, { inProcessSubscription: processSub });
}
```

When the query is executed the response is something like `{ n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }`

If i call my function like that :

```
return this.userService.setProcessedSubUser(YYY, XXX)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.nModified !== 1) // error
      return response;
    })
```

the code crash because `nModified dosen't exist on response`.

What type i need to put in place of the `???` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just create the interface for the return of `setProcessedSubUser` function.

```
interface IUpdateOne {
  n: number;
  nModified: number;
  ok: number;
}

async setProcessedSubUser(id: ObjectId, processSub: ProcessSubscriptionInterface): Promise<IUpdateOne> {
  return this.userModel.updateOne({ _id: id }, { inProcessSubscription: processSub });
}
```

Comment: I do that but i search for the "real" mongoose type response (if this type exist of course)

Comment: If you take a look at `@types/mongoose` package, you can see the type definition as below. They define response as `raw` with type `any` . 
updateOne(conditions: FilterQuery<T>, doc: UpdateQuery<T>,
      callback?: (err: any, raw: any) => void): Query<any> & QueryHelpers;
    updateOne(conditions: FilterQuery<T>, doc: UpdateQuery<T>, options: ModelUpdateOptions,
      callback?: (err: any, raw: any) => void): Query<any> & QueryHelpers;